# why views do not appear when we use thread

Tags: android, multithreading

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);

    new Thread(new BTThread()).start();
}
```

in BTThread, there is  public void run() method to do Thread.sleep(3000)first and then jump to another Activity. But during the first Activity time, we cannot see the content of activity_welcome.
if anyone get any ideas about this, i am so appreciate to have your help.

Comment: what is activity_welcome? pls give us some more code

Comment: Post all your Activty

Comment: You should not be launching activity from background thread. UI related stuff should be handled by the main thread. Use handlers and messages.

Answer (score 0):

You can't start a new activity on a thread other than the main thread.

If BTThread is an inner class of your activity you can call

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //startActivity
    }
});
```